# How to set password in MIFARE Classic 1k NFC Card

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am using the MiFare Classic 1K  card in my application, please let me know how to set a  password so that unauthorized users will not read/write cards.

Answer (score -1):

To set a password into the Classic card, you should have smart card commands based on reader you have selected. Which reader you are using?

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer.